# After Effects Mask is cropping down resolution

Tags: after-effects, mask

I have two videos, from one I create a mask.

In preview I have output fine.

Preview:
[image]

In RAM preview and render queue, output is weird:
[image]

I am a beginner ,using After Effects CS6 trial.

I have followed several masks tutorials, not a single tutorial has addressed this issue. I am using no effects at all, there are only 2 videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the RAM preview resolution to full.